# Should @3x images be 3 times larger or 4 times larger than original iPhone images?

Tags: ios, iphone, resolution

If an image was 50×50 pixels on an iPhone 1/3G, then you will need to create another image at 100x100 pixels and add `@2x` to the filename in order to optimize for the iPhone 4/5/6. You will also need to create a third image and add `@3x` to the filename in order to optimize for the upcoming iPhone 6 Plus. But what size does this `@3x` image need to be? Is it 150×150 pixels or 200×200 pixels? In other words, do you multiply by 2 with each new size, or is the overall size simply three times larger than the iPhone 1/3G size (as the name `@3x` would suggest)?

Comment: In "2x" and "3x", you calculate 2^(n-1) for the number and multiply the size that many times. "2x" —> 2 times, "3x" —> 4 times. (No, not really. Is this a trick question?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be 3x the original image along each axis.  Thus if the original image was 50x50, the @3x image should be 150x150.  (You could actually consider this to be nine times the original size, since it's nine times as many pixels.)

Answer (score 0):

Multiply your @2x image by 1.5 (make it 50% larger) to get the @3x size.

Since most newer (iOS8+) apps won't even need to support @1x images since they won't run on that hardware anyway... it is probably common that @2x images will be your "base" size, so this is may the most useful calculation to know.

Example:

```
@2x image is 56x56

56 * 1.5 = 84

@3x image = 84x84
```

Comment: While there are no 1x iPhones, there are still 1x iPads if a developer is working on an iPad app.